# Webapp creates file with strange Group Name

Tags: php, linux, file-permissions

I'm having trouble with my website/application setting strange Group names to new files.

Whenever I create a new file from my website (a log file, txt file, anything) it sets the User as webapp (correctly), but the Group name as `4294967295`

If I use terminal to ssh into my instance and try to get some data on that user it doesn't return anything. For example,

```
$ sudo groups 4294967295
groups: 4294967295: No such user
```

Further, I can't add this mystery group to any of my other users.

This is making things difficult because I have to run my cron jobs as a different user and I would like to let them both write to the same log (so they both must share a group).

I recognize that it's strange (and maybe meaningful) that 4294967295 is the highest number one can reach with 32 bits.

Any ideas or suggestions? I don't have an extensive linux background and haven't had much luck searching for answers.

I'm using Amazon AWS and an ec2-instance.

Thanks.

Additional Info:

How'd I get that group name?

```
ls -l
-rwxrwxr-x 1 webapp 4294967295  8347 Apr 16 17:35 log_2013-04-16.txt

groups 4294967295
groups: 4294967295: No such user
```

Additional Info #2:

```
$ file /bin/ls
/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=0x083f0a5a25fb311dae23412bcc79f384a865e7d4, stripped

$ groups webapp
webapp : webapp ec2-user
```

Additional Info #3:

```
$ cat group
root:x:0:
bin:x:1:bin,daemon
daemon:x:2:bin,daemon
sys:x:3:bin,adm
adm:x:4:adm,daemon
tty:x:5:
disk:x:6:
lp:x:7:daemon
mem:x:8:
kmem:x:9:
wheel:x:10:ec2-user
mail:x:12:mail
uucp:x:14:
man:x:15:
games:x:20:
gopher:x:30:
video:x:39:
dip:x:40:
ftp:x:50:
lock:x:54:
audio:x:63:
nobody:x:99:
users:x:100:
utmp:x:22:
utempter:x:35:
cdrom:x:11:
tape:x:33:
dialout:x:18:
floppy:x:19:
ec2-user:x:500:webapp
saslauth:x:76:
mailnull:x:47:
smmsp:x:51:
ssh_keys:x:499:
ntp:x:38:
sshd:x:74:
tcpdump:x:72:
screen:x:84:
dbus:x:81:
webapp:x:501:ec2-user
apache:x:48:
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are using the `groups` cmd the wrong way. Use it like:

```
groups webapp_user
```

and it will give you the groups where the webapp_user belongs to.

---

I expect the fact that the group name is set to 2^32 a display problem or you retrieve the group name the wrong way. Can you explain how you get the 2^32? With source code?

Comment: I've edited my original post. I showed the results of a `ls -l` and showed the results of checking the groups of a user

Comment: `groups webapp` = `webapp : webapp ec2-user`

Comment: `sudo usermod -a -G 4294967295 webapp` = `usermod: group '4294967295' does not exist`

Comment: can you add output of  `file /bin/ls` ?

Comment: I added the additional commands and their results to the question. I'm on a different project now (but still using AWS and their Linux container) and this issue is still appearing

Comment: @TimSum I guess the group id is by AWS convention (maybe because they assume that no real group with that id can exist) and you missed to create a group with that id.

Comment: So do you think I should create a group with that id? That way I can add webapp and ec2-user to that group and hopefully reduce my permissions issues.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking. Sounds logic, isn't it?

Comment: Further, I've checked it with a vanilla EC2 instance. There is no group with that id.. I guess it is related to some of your actions.

Comment: The strange thing is there's no group with that ID on this machine either. I displayed the contents of the `/etc/groups` file above. I'm not familiar enough with linux to know where/how it's getting that group name.

Comment: How did you transfered the files to the server? what is the origin of the files?

Comment: The application files were created on my computer, then uploaded using elasticbeanstalk's git integration `git aws.push`. So after beanstalk deploys the application to the instance everything has user&group of `webapp`. The strange files are those that are created BY the application - like when a script creates and writes to a log file.